# Mover Arquivo em Java

Tags: java

Como eu consigo mudar o diretório de um arquivo em java? Já pesquisei bastante e não consegui achar, uma forma funcional para mover arquivos para outro diretório em java.

Comment: http://www.arquivodecodigos.net/dicas/java-como-mover-um-arquivo-para-outro-diretorio-457.html

Comment: Não funcionou, como disse eu já havia pesquisado bastante e já havia visto este exemplo neste site.

Answer (score 2):

Tente da seguinte forma:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // copia os dados
    InputStream in;
    // escreve os dados
    OutputStream out;
    try{
        // arquivos que vamos copiar
        File toFile = new File("toFile.txt");
        // destino para onde vamos mover o arquivo
        File fromFile = new File("newfolder/newFile.txt");
        //verifica se o arquivo existe
        if(!fromFile.exists()){
            //verifica se a pasta existe
            if(!fromFile.getParentFile().exists()){
                //cria a pasta
                fromFile.getParentFile().mkdir();
            }
            // cria o arquivo
            fromFile.createNewFile();
        }
        in = new FileInputStream(toFile);
        out = new FileOutputStream(fromFile);
        // buffer para transportar os dados
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        // enquanto tiver dados para ler..
        while((length = in.read(buffer)) > 0 ){
            // escreve no novo arquivo
            out.write(buffer, 0 , length);
        }

        in.close();
        out.close();
        //apaga o arquivo antigo
        toFile.delete();

    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado.

Comment: vlw esse foi o único que funcionou depois de muita pesquisa